# Frequency table from multiple columns with unique variables per row

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

In my dataset `test`, I would like generate a frequency table based on two columns - `start` and `end`.  My objective is to only count a unique letter once per row even it appears in both columns.  For example, in the first row "C" should be counted only as one.  In row 4, "B" should be counted once and "A" should be counted once as they are not the same.  I know that I should use the `unique()` function somehow in but am not sure how to combine that with `table()` to generate a frequency table that counts repeated letter in a row as one (`NA` values should be omitted).   Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
> test
   start  end
1      C    C
2      A <NA>
3   <NA> <NA>
4      B    A
5      A    A
6   <NA>    A
7   <NA>    B
8   <NA>    C
9      A <NA>
10     C    C
```

The output of the following table should be:

```
> output
  station Freq
1       A    5
2       B    2
3       C    3
```

And the test data:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(start = c("C", "A", NA, "B", "A", NA, NA, NA, 
"A", "C"), end = c("C", NA, NA, "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", NA, 
"C")), .Names = c("start", "end"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
output<- table(unlist(apply(test, 1, unique)))
output

A B C 
5 2 3
```

`apply` is not a really efficient function to use, since it's a glorified `for` loop, but it will work fine in this case.